# Having to add subview to view controller twice with lazily instantiated UI views

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, viewcontroller, lazy-initialization

When programmatically adding a lazily instantiated text field to my viewcontroller, I only got it to work when calling `view.addSubview(field)` twice, in the initiation of the textview, and in `viewDidLoad()`. Removing the one in the initializer causes a crash, and removing the one in `viewDidLoad()` doesn't let the text field appear.

```swift
class VC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.addSubview(textField)
        view.setNeedsUpdatedConstraints)
    }

    lazy var textField: UITextField! = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(field)

        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        field.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
        field.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1).isActive = true

        return field
     } ()
}
```

Removing the `view.addSubview(textField)` in `viewDidLoad()` does not cause an error, but nothing shows up. Removing the `view.addSubview(field)` in the initializer causes a crash with the following error: `Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000469380 "UITextField:0x7fc931023600.centerX"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000469480 "UIView:0x7fc92f60c690.centerX"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.`

Why are both calls necessary? Does this cause problems? What would be a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `textField` declared?

Comment: forgot to change the variable name for this example, whoops

Comment: What's the error when you remove the one in the initializer? Please put the error in your question (not in a comment).

Comment: I added it. @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the text field as a subview in the `textField` initializer because of the constraints. You can't setup the constraints until the view has been added.

You seem to need the call to add the text field in `viewDidLoad` because without it, the lazy initializer is never called. So you don't actually need to call `addSubview(textField)`. You just need any reference to `textField` to trigger the initializer.

Unrelated but there is no reason for `textField` to be declared as implicitly unwrapped.